# JOOQ checking for null fields in a Record object after LEFT JOIN?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have a query in JOOQ, which contains a LEFT OUTER JOIN with another table. This is intentional, as there is no guarantee a corresponding record will exist, in which case I still want to retrieve the value from the former table, and supply the missing fields with defaults.

However, since the `getValue()` function with a default parameter is getting deprecated, how can I check whether the field contains a NULL value?

It's easy enough with strings, but a boolean value simply returns as `false`, meaning I can't check whether it really was set to false, or it's just what JOOQ decided to return.

I've tried:

```
if (record.field(MY_TABLE.SOME_BOOLEAN) != null) {
    ...
}
```

but that doesn't work, as the return value of the `field()` function isn't null, even if the value of the field is. I've also tried

```
if (record.field(MY_TABLE.SOME_BOOLEAN).isNull()){
   ...
}
```

but that isn't a valid Java conditional.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're trying won't work:

```java
if (record.field(MY_TABLE.SOME_BOOLEAN) != null) {  }
```

`Record.field()` will return a `Field` reference. The idea is that your record may not have been created from `MY_TABLE`, but it might still contain a `SOME_BOOLEAN` column, `Record.field()` will return that `SOME_BOOLEAN` column from the record.

What you're looking for is simply:

```java
if (record.get(MY_TABLE.SOME_BOOLEAN) != null) {  }
```

Do note that jOOQ has no way of distinguishing whether the `SOME_BOOLEAN` column was actually `NULL` in your database, or if `LEFT JOIN` did not return any row. This is just how SQL works. If you want to check whether your `LEFT JOIN` actually found a child row, you could check for the `null` value in a `NOT NULL` column, such as a primary key:

```java
if (record.get(MY_TABLE.ID) != null) {  }
```

Comment: is there any way to check if all fields in record are null ?

Comment: @pppavan: Yes there is. While you could just loop over all fields, there are other options. Mind asking a new question and I'll show the algorithm there, so others can profit, too.